# Automatically add data to copied text

Tags: javascript, windows, copy-paste

How can a javascript help me autodetect the copied content from a tool on windows and automatically add text at the beginning of the copied text from the tool..
Also, how do I patch the tool in with the code so that anything copied from other tools doesn't have the text  added to the copied content.
I need this because I have a software token tool which generates tokens. Now everytime when I copy from the tool (TOKEN) , I have to enter the pin (1234) and then paste the copied token. I have to do this about 100 times a day and it gets irritating. So I thought I could get help from you guys on this.
Could you help me sort this out end to end??

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely difficult to help you without any code. You might want to look at the following for a guide

```
var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
var pin = document.getElmenentById('pin').value;
var newValue = pin + token;
```